# Short story about a man on Mars searching for the rover Opportunity before its signal is lost forever

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, mars

I've been talking to my friends about Oppy (Opportunity) and I mentioned reading a short story pertaining to it in a Science magazine. Now I'm dumb and it's been well over a year since reading it and I'm not 100% sure what magazine it was in. I am like 80% sure it was called "The first" and due to its title it's kinda hard to search for.

It's a story about a man on Mars searching out Opportunity before its signal is lost forever. I'm not sure how to find it and it was really really good.

Comment: Hi there! That's some good info already; although it'd be cool if you could take a look at [these guidelines on story-ID](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if that triggers any more memories you could [edit] in. For instance, was it in English, was it a translation? Was the magazine fairly new at the time or had it been published like two weeks after Opportunity's launch? As well as anything else you could remember, as it might be stuff other people remembered as well, and could lead to a successful ID. Cheers :)